# How to place two divs besides each other? first div contain a form, second div contain google map

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm having trouble putting two divs besides each other.
First div contain a form, second div contain google map.
I can't figure out what is the mistake.

Html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first">[contact-form-7 id="116" title="Contact form"]</div>
  <div id="second">
    <iframe style="border: 0;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3391.3063811555426!2d35.20240968523232!3d31.789398981281416!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x1502d7d634ea0083%3A0x563ea54b03caa6a8!2sCompuskills!5e0!3m2!1siw!2sil!4v1488218811643" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; 
 }
#first {
    width: 70%;
    float:left; 
}
#second {
    width: 30%;
    float:left;
```

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; 
 }
#first {
    width: 70%;
    float:left; 
}
#second {
    width: 30%;
    float:left;


div.wpcf7 {
0;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

div.wpcf7-response-output {
 margin: 2em 0.5em 1em;
 padding: 0.2em 1em;
}

div.wpcf7 .screen-reader-response {
 position: absolute;
 overflow: hidden;
 clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
 height: 1px;
 width: 1px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
}

div.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok {
 border: 2px solid #398f14;
}

div.wpcf7-mail-sent-ng {
 border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}

div.wpcf7-spam-blocked {
 border: 2px solid #ffa500;
}

div.wpcf7-validation-errors {
 border: 2px solid #f7e700;
}

.wpcf7-form-control-wrap {
 position: relative;
}

span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip {
 color: #f00;
 font-size: 1em;
 display: block;
}

.use-floating-validation-tip span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip {
 position: absolute;
 top: 20%;
 left: 20%;
 z-index: 100;
 border: 1px solid #ff0000;
 background: #fff;
 padding: .2em .8em;
}

span.wpcf7-list-item {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 0 0 1em;
}

span.wpcf7-list-item-label::before,
span.wpcf7-list-item-label::after {
 content: " ";
}

.wpcf7-display-none {
 display: none;
}

div.wpcf7 .ajax-loader {
 visibility: hidden;
 display: inline-block;
 background-image: url('../../images/ajax-loader.gif');
 width: 16px;
 height: 16px;
 border: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 0 0 4px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

div.wpcf7 .ajax-loader.is-active {
 visibility: visible;
}

div.wpcf7 div.ajax-error {
 display: none;
}

div.wpcf7 .placeheld {
 color: #888;
}

div.wpcf7 .wpcf7-recaptcha iframe {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

div.wpcf7 input[type="file"] {
 cursor: pointer;
}

div.wpcf7 input[type="file"]:disabled {
 cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first">[contact-form-7 id="116" title="Contact form"]</div>
  <div id="second">
    <iframe style="border: 0;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embedpb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3391.3063811555426!2d35.20240968523232!3d31.789398981281416!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x1502d7d634ea0083%3A0x563ea54b03caa6a8!2sCompuskills!5e0!3m2!1siw!2sil!4v1488218811643" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try 50% width each?

Comment: You can also use a ul and in the style use display:inline.

Comment: your wrapper div width is 100% and your inner divs; combined width is 140% they should always equal or less than wrapper so that they wont overlap

Comment: Masivuye Cokile- I changed it.it's not that.

Comment: Can you post the actual contents and styling of your form? I've thrown this all in a [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/3z6uyesr/), and it works fine. So I'm guessing it's something in the styling of your form.

Comment: reduce the size of the inner div's to 30% each then and also your iframe width is 600px make the width so it can take 100% of the inner div thus making iframe width 100% instead of 600px @sara

Comment: It's inside a div. the 30% and 70% or on the div how can it be effected from the style of the form?

Comment: also did a fiddle it displaying as you want, maybe can u add a screenshot? @sara

Comment: @sara easy. If the form sets for example `position: absolute; right: 0;` it would completely mess up the layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `div`s may be inheriting some padding or borders from other rules in your stylesheet, which makes the width of the `div`s add up to more than 100%. Try setting `box-sizing: border-box` to account for that.

Alternatively, check for any inherited margins.

Answer (score 0):

Your elements are each 70%. It is not possible for them to float next to each other if together they take up more than the width of the page. The first width + the second width added together needs to be less than 100.

Comment: It had been a copy mistake. One is 70% and the other 30%